# Why do my MVC application gives errors on a cloud server?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, cloud

I have a MVC web application and most of its data transfer through webapi controller. It works fine in **IIS local server** but it does not work in **cloud server**(SmarterASP.net). I have leased a space from smarterasp.net and it gives me numerous errors. Few of them are as follows

[image]

[image]

Could anyone tell me how to fix these errors?

My Jquery links are as follows

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/js/jquery-1.10.2.js")"></script>
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/js/jquery-ui.js")"></script>
```

Comment: user5246938 You need to look at the path to load jQuery.  My guess is that it is wrong and jQuery is not being loaded

Comment: What is the URL of your jquery library? seems like isn't deployed.

Comment: that is because your jquery is not attached properly

Comment: Hi, go to the network tab and look for jquery, maybe, exists any problem when the http get that call jquery is launch

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers How to check that is attached or not cause local iis server works fine

Comment: @JulitoAvellaneda There is no issue with network tab

Comment: @Max It is time to break out the developer tools in the browser and look at the generated html to see what the link really is.  While there, you should look for any errors in the console.  What you are doing with the links is not the MVC way.  You should either be using a Bundle with a CDN backing store link and referencing the Bundle as a ScriptBundle or you should reference jQuery directly from a CDN.